# JPA Entity did not save in database after added new @Lob field

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have an issue related with that JPA enity not saved in database, so
after added new clob field in jpa entity - entity doesn't save in database
I use websphere, spring 4.3.13 and Oracle11g

my jpa enity before

```
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "UserRecord")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class UserRecord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "PR_KEY")
    private String prKey;

    //Business Key
    @Column(name = "businessId", length = 100, unique = false)
    private String businessId;

    //Business Key
    @Column(name = "name", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    //Business Key
    @Column(name = "surname", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "updateDateTime", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private Timestamp updateDateTime;

    @Version
    private int version;

    @Column(name = "user", length = 100000)
    @Lob
    private byte[] user;


    public UserRecord(String businessId, String name, String surname, Timestamp updateDateTime, byte[] user) {
        this.businessId = businessId;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.updateDateTime = updateDateTime;
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

and after

```
import lombok.*;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
    import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.sql.Timestamp;

    @Entity
    @Audited
    @Table(name = "UserRecord")
    @NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
    public class UserRecord {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
        @Column(name = "PR_KEY")
        private String prKey;

        //Business Key
        @Column(name = "businessId", length = 100, unique = false)
        private String businessId;

        //Business Key
        @Column(name = "name", length = 100, nullable = false)
        private String name;

        //Business Key
        @Column(name = "surname", length = 100, nullable = false)
        private String surname;

        @Column(name = "updateDateTime", length = 50, nullable = false)
        private Timestamp updateDateTime;

        @Version
        private int version;

        @Column(name = "user", length = 100000)
        @Lob
        private byte[] user;

        @Column(name = "userXml")
        @Lob
        private String userXml;

        public UserRecord(String businessId, String name, String surname, Timestamp updateDateTime, byte[] user, String userXml) {
            this.businessId = businessId;
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.updateDateTime = updateDateTime;
            this.user = user;
            this.userXml = userXml;
        }
    }
```

serice layer code fragment is 
before

```
  record = new RiskMetricRecord(businessId, name, surname, updateDateTimeTimestamp, serialize(userToSave));
```

after

```
 record = new RiskMetricRecord(businessId, name, surname, updateDateTimeTimestamp, serialize(userToSave), userToSave);
```

And my Jparepository is:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRecord, String> {

}
```

So, when I try to save my entity in database after added field @Lob String in JPA entity - there is no error messages, but, in database there is no changes too..

More info:
database table is

```
-- auto-generated definition
CREATE TABLE USERRECORD
(
  PR_KEY            VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY,
  BUSINESSID VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  USER        BLOB,
  NAME    VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SURNAME     VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  VERSION           NUMBER(10)         NOT NULL,
  UPDATEDATETIME    TIMESTAMP(3),
  USERXML     CLOB
)
/
```

Tried:
1)

```
 @Lob
    @Column(name = "userXml", columnDefinition = "CLOB")
    private String userXml;
```

Comment: Is the column for @Lob String userXml, CLOB on Oracle? This is the type for text data

Comment: @Brother updated an issue. Yes, there is CLOB on Oracle and String in JPA. Is this correct?

Comment: can you see my update about "CLOB NOT NULL"

Comment: do you have the column "riskMetricXml" on DB? In your example you said you tried this name for Column.

Comment: corrected example. May be the root cause in that two @Lob elemetns in JPA entity?

Comment: @Brother updated and answered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193894/discussion-between-brother-and-roberto).

Answer (score 0):

When I worked on persisting BLOB in app, I tried byte[], it did not save the data. Then I changed data type of property in my entity class to java.sql.Blob, which fixed the problem.

In your case, you are working with CLOB, then change data type of properties from String or byte[] to java.sql.Clob.

```
@Column(name = "user", length = 100000)
@Lob
private Clob user;

@Column(name = "userXml")
@Lob
private Clob userXml;
```

So before your persist entity, you have to transform payload of user and userXml properties to Clob objects.

To create Clob object, you can use Hibernate utilities.

```
Hibernate.getLobCreator(getHibernateSession()).createClob(stringvar);
```

Answer (score -1):

in JPA, you can easily use TEXT property as mentioned here, it will store any amount of data. Also, no need to define length manually. And also delete `@Lob`, there is no need. Keep in mind that first delete your column at DB and re-create to update its definition.

```
@Column(name = "userXml", columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String userXml;
```

Comment: in my database it must be CLOB column or just VARCHAR?

Comment: unfortunatly it not helped

Comment: Oracle has a `TEXT` datatype does it?? Anyway that attribute is only used in schema generation.

Comment: @Roberto - In your DB, field type need to be varchar only.